# mysql query get today and tommrows date

Tags: php, mysql

```
SELECT
   doctors. fullname,
   dutyroster.date,
   dutyroster.time
FROM
   dutyroster
INNER JOIN doctors ON doctors.docid = dutyroster.docid
WHERE doctors.docid = $doc_id AND
dutyroster.date = DATE(NOW()) AND DATE(NOW())+ INTERVAL 1 DAY
ORDER BY dutyroster.`date`  ASC";
```

this query is used to find specific doctors information from a table called dutyroster. i want to get the docs shedule information for current day and tommrow only.. but this doesnt work.

and i made a second one which is also not working since it returns current one and all the next dates also

```
SELECT
    doctors. fullname,
    dutyroster.date,
    dutyroster.time
FROM
    dutyroster
INNER JOIN doctors ON doctors.docid = dutyroster.docid
WHERE doctors.docid = $doc_id AND
DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 2 DAY) <= dutyroster.date
ORDER BY dutyroster.`date`  ASC"
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```sql
... AND dutyroster.date = DATE(NOW()) AND DATE(NOW())+ INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

try

```sql
... AND (dutyroster.date = CURDATE() OR 
         dutyroster.date = CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY))
```

or in more concise way, as @MarcM suggested

```sql
... AND dutyroster.date IN (CURDATE(), CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 day)
```

Comment: `dutyroster.date IN (curdate(), curdate() + interval 1 day)` is a little more concise. now() may be problematic since it includes h:m:s and could throw off the comparison if `.date` is a datetime field, not just date. the new version should be an `OR`, however. but otherwise +1.

Comment: @MarcB DATE(NOW()) gives only a date, but I totally agree `IN` with `CURDATE()` are more concise.

Comment: Ah doh... sorry, it's been a LOOOONG day. missed the date() part completely.

Comment: dutyroster.date IN (curdate(), curdate() + interval 1 day). This one Works perfectly Fine

Comment: @AhmedYaser See updated answer. It obviously should be OR between both conditions, or use `IN` which is the same.

Answer (score 0):

From your first attempt it almost looks like you are trying to program COBOL!
Also, for future reference "this doesn't work" is not a helpful comment. You should say what actually happens.

Anyway, try changing your where clause to either:

WHERE doctors.docid = $doc_id AND
(dutyroster.date = CURRENT_DATE OR dutyroster.date = CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 1 DAY)

or:

WHERE doctors.docid = $doc_id AND
dutyroster.date IN (CURRENT_DATE, CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 1 DAY))